# you need variety (is it necessary the indefinite article?)

Tags: phrase-usage

If I use the phrase

> You need a variety ... / You need variety ...

when should I use the indefinite article and when shouldn't I?

Comment: There is no "general principle" regarding which article (definite, indefinite, or *zero*) to use before the word ***variety***. It all depends on ***context***. But it's certainly worth noting that [*the **zero article** is most common between **like** and **variety***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+variety%2Clike+a+variety%2Clike+the+variety&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20a%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20the%20variety%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...but [*between **need** and **variety***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need+variety%2Cneed+a+variety%2Cneed+the+variety&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneed%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20a%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20the%20variety%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cneed%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20a%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20the%20variety%3B%2Cc0) it's more likely we'll use the ***indefinite*** article. In short, unless you give an ***exact*** context, the question lacks focus.

Comment: My cat ***needs a variety*** of cat food suitable for older animals. But like any animal, my cat ***needs variety*** in her diet. And sometimes she ***needs the variety*** of cat food that helps her deal with hairballs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A variety* would be followed by *of* and a general term for the kind of things being referred to.

> I grow a variety of flowers in my garden.

*You need variety* presumably means something like 'You need new experiences or a change of scenery in your life'.